# Question ban persisting based on newbie questions over a year old

Tags: support, question-quality, users

I appear to have a question ban that has persisted for over a year, and has not reset at the six month stage. The majority of my questions have been neutrally or positively received but there are three very slightly naive questions which were downvoted (two very heavily, perhaps even draconianly).

Since it is my understanding that the software resets itself every 6 months it feels as if there must be a bug. None of my downvoted questions were poorly written, badly formatted or in any other way negatively contributing to the site.

I also recently received the 'popular question' award for one of the downvoted questions.

Comment: Your understating is incorrect; see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/270345 for more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The majority of my questions have been neutrally or positively received but there are three very slightly naive questions which were downvoted

You actually have quite a few downvoted questions, they were just [automatically deleted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) by the system.

> Since it is my understanding that the software resets itself every 6 months it feels as if there must be a bug.

I'm not sure where you heard this, but [question bans never expire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/145982). The recommended solution is to post good answers, as answer upvotes can get your account to a point where the question ban no longer applies. You can also try [contacting Stack Exchange](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) and explaining the situation.

Comment: The ban appears to have been revoked now. Thank you for taking the time to explain. When a question ban is in place there is a message which appears saying 'in six months you will be given the opportunity to ask another question', which is what led me to believe the ban would be lifted at this time, or that there would be the opportunity to get it lifted.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter We don't have the ability to unban you, and you still show up as question banned for me; as far as I know it will never go away unless you post some answers that get enough upvotes or a Stack Exchange employee unbans you manually. I've never heard of that 6 months message before, I'm not sure what it's referring to

Comment: So Answer activity is the only activity that counts for this? Not other point garnering/site improving activity, such as edits?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter Hmm, good question. Stack Exchange hasn't shared much info about how bans work; the only reason we know that upvotes on answers can help with a question ban is because it was mentioned by a developer in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68884/why-cant-i-ask-questions-on-stackoverflow/68885#68885). So you can try other things like editing, but I don't have any evidence as to if it will help or not